# About advent security towers

Tags: xcom-2

in a "kill VIP" mission, I've hacked one of the 2 turrets succesfully and it gave me "Reduce enemy will by 50%".

But then, the second turret became unhackable. It was still rotating with red lights, but no matter how close I was (even melee) it was impossible to hack (no hack symbol appearing on my specialist actions).

Is it normal or a bug ?

Answer (score 5):

This is normal. You can only hack one security tower per mission. So you should check which tower gives you which bonus and then decide which one is the better deal for you.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But if the second tower is disabled (which it is since it doesnt trigger any alert when I get close) why not remove the rotating and red lasers animation ? not a visual bug ?